# Interfacing a USB webcam to an Arduino board

Tags: arduino, usb

I'm trying to connect a USB webcam to an Arduino board (Intel Galileo), the Galileo is powered by a 400 Mhz processor, has 512 Mb of RAM and 8 Gb of external storage (SD Card). I'm a computer science major and electronics is not really my field, what I understood to this point is that if this was a serial connection I would've used the first and second (0 and 1) pins to make the connection (Rx and Tx). Now I understand there is a difference between USB and serial, but USB is somehow serial? Anyhow I've attached both a picture of the camera cable and of the board and would appreciate the most simplified way to make the connection.
Thanks![image]

[image]

Comment: "USB" is serial, and "serial" is serial, but "serial" is actually "UART".

Comment: "Serial" is purely a concept, not a protocol.  In the same way that "vehicle" covers cars, lorries, trains, planes, etc...

Comment: How is an Intel Galileo an Arduino?

Comment: It's an Arduino
See : http://arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelGalileo

Comment: @user3601592 it's "Arduino Certified"...but it's not an Arduino.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plug the camera into the USB host port.

The Intel Galileo [documentation](http://www.intel.com/newsroom/kits/quark/galileo/pdfs/Intel_Galileo_Datasheet.pdf) says it has a USB host port, which is [labelled 'USB HOST' on the PCB](http://arduino.cc/en/uploads/ArduinoCertified/IntelGalileo_fabD_Front.jpg). Plugging a keyboard or mouse into this port (using a standard USB cable) will allow it to be used with the [USBHost library](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/USBHost), so doing so with a camera should also make the correct electrical connections.

You will then have to use linux and OpenCV to support your camera as in [this thread](https://communities.intel.com/thread/48204?start=0&tstart=0), or search for "intel galileo usb camera" online for other examples.

Comment: Thank you for replying, that's actually a micro-usb port and webcams are using a "standard" USB 2.0, can you help me with that please?

Comment: @user3601592 buy an adapter.

Comment: Would that work for sure? (This project started to drain my resources)

Comment: I'll be installing a Linux image later on so are you sure this will work? Thanks

Comment: @user3601592 searching for "intel galileo usb camera" brings up this thread https://communities.intel.com/thread/48204?start=0&tstart=0 where various people have various issues, and also details of which particular adapter.